# Endereço e portas de destino UDP não aparecem

Tags: php, cmd, prompt

Estou criando em `PHP` **uma página que rastreia o trafego de pacotes UDP** da minha máquina. Minha intenção era obter a lista assim:

```
____________________________________________________________________________
| Proto |      Endereço local     |     Endereço externo     |   Estado    |
|  UDP  |   meu Ip : nº porta     | IP de destino : nº porta | ESTABLISHED |
|       |exemplo: 192.168.A.A:1000|exemplo:187.173.A.AAA:2300|             |
```

Mas usando o comando `netstat -a` está imprimindo algo +- assim:

```
____________________________________________________________________________
| Proto |      Endereço local     |     Endereço externo     |   Estado    |
|  UDP  |     192.168.A.A:1000    |            *:*           |             |
```

Ou seja ele não mostra nem o IP nem a porta de destino, e isto só acontece com pacotes UDP, pois quando rastreio os pacotes TCP o endereço de destino aparece normalmente. Executando no próprio prompt de comando como Administrador obtenho o mesmo resultado sem o retorno do endereço de destino. Mas há pacotes UDP trafegando na rede, pois estou usando o programa *Wireshark* para acompanhá-los. Mas eu preciso rastrea-los com o php para usar os dados depois.

Tenho uma página `rastreador.php` que executa o comando `netstat -a` e transforma o valor retornado em um array e imprime na tela o array:

```
$exec = exec('netstat -a', $array3);

echo '<fieldset>';
if($exec){
echo '<pre>'.'<br>'.'<B>Executando Comando netstat -a: </B>'.'<br>';
var_dump($array3);
echo '</pre>';
}
echo '</fieldset>';
```

mas ele não está imprimindo as portas que eu quero. Se alguém souber o porquê disso ou souber o que significa estes asteríscos `*:*` que são retornados ao executar o comando ficarei muito agradecida.

saída do `var_dump`:

```
Executando Comando netstat -a: 
array (size=139)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string 'Conex�es ativas' (length=15)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => string '  Proto  Endere�o local         Endere�o externo       Estado' (length=61)
  4 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  5 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  6 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  7 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  8 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  9 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  10 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:6646           LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  11 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:47984          LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  12 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:47989          LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  13 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  14 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  15 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  16 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  17 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  18 => string '  TCP    0.0.0.0:49689          LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  19 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:9990         LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  20 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:23403        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  21 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:30800        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  22 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:30900        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  23 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:31752        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  24 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:50022        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:31752  TIME_WAIT' (length=64)
  25 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:50023        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:31752  TIME_WAIT' (length=64)
  26 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:50025        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:31752  TIME_WAIT' (length=64)
  27 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:50028        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:31752  TIME_WAIT' (length=64)
  28 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:50029        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:31752  TIME_WAIT' (length=64)
  29 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:50035        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:31752  TIME_WAIT' (length=64)
  30 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:63905        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:65001  ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  31 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  32 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:65001        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  33 => string '  TCP    127.0.0.1:65001        LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:63905  ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  34 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:139       LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  35 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:49291     f50001:imaps           ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  36 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:49480     6:http                 ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  37 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:49537     stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  38 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:49951     8.43.72.98:https       TIME_WAIT' (length=64)
  39 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:49953     199.16.156.232:https   ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  40 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:49981     ec2-54-186-9-130:https  ESTABLISHED' (length=67)
  41 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:49991     gru06s26-in-f14:https  ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  42 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:50020     gru09s19-in-f14:https  ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  43 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:50021     ec2-54-215-241-186:https  TIME_WAIT' (length=67)
  44 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:50024     openrg:2555            TIME_WAIT' (length=64)
  45 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:50031     a23-76-248-182:https   ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  46 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:50033     64.4.54.254:https      ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  47 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:50034     190.98.146.42:http     ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  48 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:50038     gru09s19-in-f14:http   ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  49 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:50039     LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:http   TIME_WAIT' (length=64)
  50 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:63890     msnbot-65-52-108-192:https  ESTABLISHED' (length=71)
  51 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:63931     bn3sch020010553:https  ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  52 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:63971     bc:35061               ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  53 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:63974     ec2-52-24-34-19:5222   ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  54 => string '  TCP    192.168.1.37:64495     ec2-54-225-235-246:https  ESTABLISHED' (length=69)
  55 => string '  TCP    [::]:80                LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  56 => string '  TCP    [::]:135               LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  57 => string '  TCP    [::]:445               LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  58 => string '  TCP    [::]:2869              LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  59 => string '  TCP    [::]:3306              LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  60 => string '  TCP    [::]:5357              LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  61 => string '  TCP    [::]:49664             LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  62 => string '  TCP    [::]:49665             LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  63 => string '  TCP    [::]:49666             LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  64 => string '  TCP    [::]:49667             LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  65 => string '  TCP    [::]:49668             LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  66 => string '  TCP    [::]:49689             LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:0      LISTENING' (length=64)
  67 => string '  TCP    [::1]:80               LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:50037  ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  68 => string '  TCP    [::1]:50037            LAPTOP-3R4M4UFI:http   ESTABLISHED' (length=66)
  69 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*' (length=35)
  70 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:3544           *:*' (length=35)
  71 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*' (length=35)
  72 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*' (length=35)
  73 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*' (length=35)
  74 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*' (length=35)
  75 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*' (length=35)
  76 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*' (length=35)
  77 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*' (length=35)
  78 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*' (length=35)
  79 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*' (length=35)
  80 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:6646           *:*' (length=35)
  81 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:50291          *:*' (length=35)
  82 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:54620          *:*' (length=35)
  83 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:58571          *:*' (length=35)
  84 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:61114          *:*' (length=35)
  85 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:61117          *:*' (length=35)
  86 => string '  UDP    0.0.0.0:62952          *:*' (length=35)
  87 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*' (length=35)
  88 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:48400        *:*' (length=35)
  89 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:48401        *:*' (length=35)
  90 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:53982        *:*' (length=35)
  91 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:54615        *:*' (length=35)
  92 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:54616        *:*' (length=35)
  93 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:54617        *:*' (length=35)
  94 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:54618        *:*' (length=35)
  95 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:54619        *:*' (length=35)
  96 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:60847        *:*' (length=35)
  97 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:61116        *:*' (length=35)
  98 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:65000        *:*' (length=35)
  99 => string '  UDP    127.0.0.1:65535        *:*' (length=35)
  100 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:137       *:*' (length=35)
  101 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:138       *:*' (length=35)
  102 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:1900      *:*' (length=35)
  103 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:2177      *:*' (length=35)
  104 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:5353      *:*' (length=35)
  105 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:20224     *:*' (length=35)
  106 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:20225     *:*' (length=35)
  107 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:20226     *:*' (length=35)
  108 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:20227     *:*' (length=35)
  109 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:20228     *:*' (length=35)
  110 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:20229     *:*' (length=35)
  111 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:20230     *:*' (length=35)
  112 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:20231     *:*' (length=35)
  113 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:53981     *:*' (length=35)
  114 => string '  UDP    192.168.1.37:56777     *:*' (length=35)
  115 => string '  UDP    [::]:500               *:*' (length=35)
  116 => string '  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*' (length=35)
  117 => string '  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*' (length=35)
  118 => string '  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*' (length=35)
  119 => string '  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*' (length=35)
  120 => string '  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*' (length=35)
  121 => string '  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*' (length=35)
  122 => string '  UDP    [::]:4500              *:*' (length=35)
  123 => string '  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*' (length=35)
  124 => string '  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*' (length=35)
  125 => string '  UDP    [::]:50292             *:*' (length=35)
  126 => string '  UDP    [::]:54621             *:*' (length=35)
  127 => string '  UDP    [::]:61115             *:*' (length=35)
  more elements...
```

Comment: Pode colocar a saída completa do var_dump?

Comment: @MagicHat coloquei

Comment: O que retorna usando `netstat -au` ?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade não executa nada, mostra as opções do comando netstat

Comment: @zekk mas não tem um modo de mostrar com qual endereço IP está conectado?

Comment: Faça o seguinte teste. Em um computador que esteja na mesma rede, deixe rodando o seguinte comando `nc -ul 6111` e nesse computador deixe rodando o seguinte comando `nc -u <ip_do_outro_pc> 6111` e rode em outro terminal o `netstat -a`

Answer (score 2):

Se você tem um servidor UDP que fez um "bind" numa certa porta então não vai aparecer mesmo o IP e a porta de destino, isso é normal.

Mesmo que exista tráfego UDP para esse servido não vai aparecer IP e porta de destino, porque não existe "conexão" UDP, cada mensagem enviada/recebida (chamada "datagrama") é independente das mensagens enviadas/recebidas anteriores/posteriores.

Clientes UDP podem se "conectar" ao servidor, mas é uma conexão "fake", apenas para facilitar a programação, para evitar especificar o endpoint destino em cada send, mas isso não tem efeito nenhum sobre as mensagens trocadas na rede.